# press(KeyCode.Enter) does not work more than once TestFX?

Tags: java, testing, javafx, testfx

I am using junit5 Testfx with jdk 11. I have the following test

```
@Test
    void should_contain_button_with_text(FxRobot robot) {
            robot.clickOn("#newCol").write("Done");
            robot.press(KeyCode.ENTER);
            robot.clickOn("#newCard").write("Cleaning");
            press(KeyCode.ENTER);
            robot.sleep(2000);
    }
```

Both `newCol` and `newCard` are textfields.

Expected result should be the robot first goes to the `newCol` and after pressing enter it should go to `newCard` and do the same.

However, it goes to `newCol` and presses enter fine but on the second press it does not work. Why is this the case. Can the `press(KeyCode)` only be pressed once?

If someone can please help me out I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you have to simulate releasing the enter key before it can be pressed again?

Comment: @Slaw thanks alot, I never knew we had to release them after. It did the trick ;)

Comment: I can't find decent documentation about this. The [wiki](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX/wiki/Robots-and-Queries) simply does not have anything related to key events, as far as I can tell. The best I could find is the documentation of [`KeyboardRobot#press(KeyCode...)`](http://testfx.github.io/TestFX/docs/javadoc/testfx-core/javadoc/org.testfx/org/testfx/robot/KeyboardRobot.html#press(javafx.scene.input.KeyCode...)), which only says: "_Presses the given keys, until explicitly released via `release(KeyCode...)`. Once pressed, `WaitForAsyncUtils.waitForFxEvents()` is called_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Slaw suggested, you first have to release the key in order to use it again.

```
 robot.press(KeyCode.ENTER).release(KeyCode.ENTER);
```

The above did the trick. Same goes for any other key actions.